# Proof Bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods

Denote the successive intervals that arise in the bisection method by $[a_1\,, b_1], [a_2\,,\, b_2], [a_3\,,\, b_3],$ and so on. Let $c_n$ be the midpoint of $[a_n, b_n]$. Show that $|c_n − c_{n+1}| = 2^{−(n+1)}(b_1−a_1)$.

Any hint on this one, not sure where to start, Thanks

Comment: Can you give $c_n$ in terms of $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: OK in terms of an and bn, cn=bn+an/2

Comment: No, that isn't the midpoint. Think of $a_n=1$, and $b_n=2$. The midpoint should be $c_n=1.5$, but your formula gives $c_n=2+1/2=2.5$.

Comment: OK in terms of an and bn, cn=(bn+an)/2, typing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mid point of $[a_n,b_n]$ is $c_n$ and its length is $b_n-a_n$, the next interval is one of $[c_n,b_b]$ or $[a_n,c_n]$, the mid points of each of these is a distance $(b_n-a_n)/4$ from $c_n$, so

$$
|c_n-c_{n+1}|=(b_n-a_n)/4=(b_{n-1}-a_{n-1})/8=|c_{n-1}-c_{n}|/2
$$

as each interval is half the length of the previous one.

Induction or another method will now confirm the resilt you are required to prove

Comment: Thanks for the help Conrad Turner.